# Spotlight: Getting MacOS 10.6 to return epub files as file type org.idpf.epub-container

Tags: macos, spotlight

I want to use the Spotlight API to find `epub` files of as file type `org.idpf.epub-container`. This works fine on Lion since Apple has added the `org.idpf.epub-container` file type to Lion.

I wrote a Spotlight importer for `.epub` files. If I run it by hand using `mdimport` with some `epub` files as input then Spotlight will find those files. But I get no results from Spotlight `NSMetaDataQuery` API. (I'm typing this from memory. Sorry if I got the name wrong.) If I reboot and retry the query I get no results. It seems like Spotlight is not using my importer even though it is listed in the output from `mdimport -L`

The attribute output from `mdimport -r` look fine. Including the file type `org.idpf.epup-container` and my defined atributes.

Does anyone have any ideas why Spotlight wouldn't use an importer that seems to work if `mdimport` is invoked explicitly?

I have more details. If I run:

mdls -name kMDItemContentType file.epub

against an epub file I get:

kMDItemContentType = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80n6dzqk"

even though if I run mdimport -d3 against the same file I get:

kMDItemContentType = "org.idpf.epub-container";

Hope this helps.

I'm going to answer my own question. The hint is that kMDItemContentType is set to something. Since it is set Spotlight isn't going to change it. (Maybe Spotlight would re-index the file if I used touch to change the file's modification date.)

But the bigger solution is to erase the Spotlight index using:

mdutil -E /Volume/Macintosh\ HD

Once Spotlight rebuilds it's index then all ePub files have the correct kMDItemContentType setting.